# Milliseconds value is not matching with the previous value in 1 second timer in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-7

I was trying to run the code mentioned below (reference taken from http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/timers.shtml), but after running this code, I have observed that Milliseconds value is not matching with the previous value. Can anybody please help me to understand this behaviour, as per my understanding milliseconds value should match at every seconds?.Please correct me, if I am wrong.

OS: Windows 7

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.50709 SP1Rel
Installed Version: Professional

---

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Started at {0:HH:mm:ss.fff}", DateTime.Now);
        // Start in three seconds, then fire every one second
        using (Timer timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(Tick), null, 3000, 1000))
        {

            // Wait for 10 seconds
            Thread.Sleep(10000);

            // Then go slow for another 10 seconds
            timer.Change(0, 2000);
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
        }

        // The timer will now have been disposed automatically due to the using
        // statement, so there won't be any other threads running, and we'll quit.
    }

    static void Tick(object state)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ticked at {0:HH:mm:ss.fff}", DateTime.Now);
    }
}
}
```

Code Output:

```
Started at 16:08:47.778
Ticked at 16:08:50.825
Ticked at 16:08:51.842
Ticked at 16:08:52.854
Ticked at 16:08:53.868
Ticked at 16:08:54.882
Ticked at 16:08:55.894
Ticked at 16:08:56.908
Ticked at 16:08:57.809
Ticked at 16:08:59.812
Ticked at 16:09:01.824
Ticked at 16:09:03.836
Ticked at 16:09:05.849
```

Comment: The accuracy of a timer is not ±0ms... consider it "about 1 second"; does that help any?

Comment: Also keep in mind that the OS determines when your process can run. At any point it can interrupt your program and give another program the chance to run.

Comment: @BG100 I meant 1 second

Comment: also time is mysterious

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(10000);` never takes exactly 10s. It means, processor give you its time, when nobody else need it, but not before 10s.